# C# Certificate Pinning

Tags: c#, validation, ssl, certificate, webclient

How do I best validate a certificate in a WebClient?

At the Moment i have this:

```
class SafeClient : WebClient
{
    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        var request = base.GetWebRequest(address);

        byte[] embeddedCert;
        using (Stream certStream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("Test.Resources.test.pfx"))
        {
            embeddedCert = new byte[certStream.Length];
            certStream.Read(embeddedCert, 0, (int)certStream.Length);
        }

        var cert = new X509Certificate2(embeddedCert, "Pass");

        (request as HttpWebRequest).ClientCertificates.Add(cert);

        return request;
    }
}
```

But how i can check the Certificate in the Response from the Server. I don't want that anybody can Read/Write the Response/Request white Charles or...

Thank you in advance and nice greetings from Germany.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your aim correctly, you want to obtain an information about server certificate after making a request.

For this HttpWebRequest provide a special delegate. [HttpWebRequest.ServerCertificateValidationCallback](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.servercertificatevalidationcallback(v=vs.110).aspx).

So, your code could look like following:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://");
request.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, error) =>
{
    //TODO:implement your custom logic
};
```

I hope, that this link will also be useful for you.
[ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.remotecertificatevalidationcallback(v=vs.110).aspx)